# How to get a nested div to move with the parent on zoom

Tags: css, html, zooming

So all of the posts I have seen are on getting your element NOT to resize or move, but the problem I am having with mine is that my element will NOT resize or move.  The div called headLogo which contains the logo as the background will not move/resize with the parent div that contains it when zoomed in or out in the browser.

Here is the CSS:

```
#headContainer {
height: 134px;
background-image: url('images/main-bg.jpg');
background-repeat: repeat-x;
overflow: hidden;}

#headWhiteImage {
position: relative;
height: 134px;
background: url('images/header-bar.png') no-repeat 50% 0 transparent!important;
z-index: 10;}

#headLogo {
position: absolute;
height: 62px;
width: 333px;
background: url('images/logo2.png') no-repeat;
left: 133px;
top: 10px;
```

Here is HTML:

```
 <div id="headContainer">
<div id="headWhiteImage">
    <div id="headLogo">
        </div>
    <div id="headMenu">
    </div>
</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  To position the logo, it needed to be in a container itself, and then float the actual logo to make it move with the zoom.

Here is the HTML:

```
    <div id="headContainer">
        <div id="headWhiteImage">
            <div id="headBarContainer">
                <div id="headLogo">

                </div> 
                <div id="headMenu">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#headContainer {
height: 134px;
background-image: url('images/main-bg.jpg');
background-repeat: repeat-x;
overflow: hidden;
}

#headWhiteImage {
position: relative;
height: 134px;
background: url('images/header-bar.png') no-repeat 50% 0 transparent!important;
z-index: 10;
}

#headBarContainer {
position: relative;
height: 75px;
width: 960px;
background-color: transparent;
margin: 0 auto; 
padding-top: 10px;
}

#headLogo {
height: 62px;
width: 333px;
background: url('images/logo2.png') no-repeat;
float: left;
margin-left: -27px;
}
```